# Postgres with recursive - result to include both grandparent and grandchildren

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query, with-statement

My family tree contains children and parents. I can write a query that returns the grandchildren for a given person using postgres `with recursive`. But how can I include the grandparent in the results? My target is to report the numbers of grandchildren, grouped by grandparent id. How do I refer to the *non-recursive* part of the query in the final results?

---

edited - example table:

```
child parent
  11   null
  12   null
  13   null
  21    11
  22    11
  31    12
  32    12
  33    12
  41    13
  81    21
  82    21
  83    21
  91    33
  92    33
```

non-recursive part of query:

```
select distinct child where parent is null -- as grandparent
```

desired result:

```
grandparent, grandchildren
     11           3
     12           2
     13           0
```

Comment: Please post how table looks like and what exactly are you expecting in output.

Comment: hi @Nik - does the updated question answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do:

```
with recursive zzz AS (
  select child AS grandparent, child AS current_child, 1 AS grand_level 
  FROM thetable AS tt
  where parent is null
 UNION
  SELECT grandparent, tt.child, grand_level+1
  FROM thetable AS tt
  JOIN zzz
    ON tt.parent = zzz.current_child
)
SELECT grandparent, COUNT(DISTINCT current_child)FILTER(WHERE grand_level = 3) AS grandchildren
FROM zzz
GROUP BY grandparent;
```

Comment: the documentation says how it works. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html